# Running TestNG tests by reading run status from Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have written a test suite in TestNG. But I want to run only those test classes which are specified as below:

Contents of the excel file are as follows:

```
S.No      Test Class      RunFlag
 1        SampleOne          Y
 2        SampleTwo          N
 3        SampleThree        Y
```

I want to run only those test classes which have 'Y' specified against them.

Following is my approach-
This is my runner class:

```
TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
    List<Class> listnerClasses = new ArrayList<Class>();
            Class[] classList = new Class[]{
                    SampleTestOne.class,
                    SampleTestTwo.class};

            listnerClasses.add(SampleListener.class);
            testNG.setDefaultSuiteName("suite");
            testNG.setListenerClasses(listnerClasses);
            testNG.setTestClasses(RunnerMethods.createClassList(classList));
            testNG.run();
```

The above class calls a method createClassList() and passes an array of Class type as parameter. This method is present in RunnerMethods Class as follows:

```
static Class[] createClassList(Class[] classList) {
        Class[] finalClassList = new Class[1];
        int counter = 0;
        for (Class cls : classList){
            String flag = readRunFlag(cls.getSimpleName());
            if(flag == "Y"){
                finalClassList[counter] = cls;
                counter++;
            }
            else
                continue;
        }

        return finalClassList;
    }
    private static String readRunFlag(String className){
        String runFlag = null;
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Q2435\\Desktop\\RunControl.xlsx"))){
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
            int rowNumber = findRow(sheet, className);
            Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);
            Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
            runFlag = cell.toString();
            workbook.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return runFlag;
    }
    private static int findRow(XSSFSheet sheet, String cellContent) {

        for (Row row : sheet) {
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals(cellContent)) {
                        return row.getRowNum();  
                    }
                }
            }
        }               
        return 0;
    }
```

The called method returns a NullPointerException. Please help me solve it.

Comment: Which line gives you the null pointer?

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: The Null Pointer Exception is thrown when I try to use the Class[] array returned by the createClassList().

Comment: Me also required this type code,still no one gave proper codes to perform this type of scenarios?

Comment: Can you please provide the code,in case issue is resolved.